# Add confirmation message after validating Portlet Preferences

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want to add a confirmation message and a redirect to my jsp when the form is validated.

I saw this in liferay's source code

```
SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, config.getPortletName() + ".doConfigure");
```

This displays a green styled message with `Param has been saved successfully`. But doesn't work. It obviously uses Configuration menu (which opens a pop-up), and I use Preferences menu, still can I adapt this line for my code?

And when I change preferences, I want a redirect in my portlet, but for now, it is still on the preferences page and I have to click on `Return to full page`.

Also, can I display error messages in the case the preferences aren't validated?

Regards. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every

```
  SessionMessages.add(actionRequest, "successfully-handled-some-action");
  SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "problem-occurred");
```

you will need a section picking it up in your jsp (otherwise nobody would know where you'd like it to appear on the page):

```
  <liferay-ui:success key="successfully-handled-some-action" message="localization-key-for-this-message"/>
  <liferay-ui:error key="problem-occurred" message="localization-key-for-this-message"/>
```

Comment: This works well. But what about the redirect on the portlet?Is it possible to be on preferences page, and when the form is correct, had a redirect on the portlet display?

Comment: Use this actionResponse.setPortletMode(PortletMode.VIEW)